# In Dart, is creating a Future, completing it and returning it less efficient than creating an immediate Future?

Tags: performance, dart, future

What is the performance difference between

```
var completer = new Completer<String>();
var future    = completer.future;
completer.complete("value");
return future;
```

and

```
var future = new Future<String>.immediate("value");
return future;
```

?

Comment: Go with `immediate()`. It's synchronous at the moment, but may [eventually become asynchronous](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3356).

Comment: I have a very good reason not to, so I really need to know what the performance difference is to see whether it's worth optimizing with `immediate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully soon `Future.immediate` will use a Completer under the hood to make it async, so any performance difference there now will go away.

Even today though, any such performance difference should be exceedingly small. All of the code in Completer and Future is synchronous and small, so the overhead consists of an allocation of a Completer and a few method invocations. That should be very, very fast.

Upshot: Stick with Completer.

Answer (score 0):

[new Future.immediate()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html#Future.immediate) and [Completer.complete()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Completer.html#complete) both return a Future with a value that is available on the next event loop. (This is implemented using new Timer(0, callback). See [future_impl.dart](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart).)

For example, these two statements behave identically:

```
  new Future.immediate('blah').then(print);
  Completer..complete('blah').future.then(print);
```

The DartVM and dart2js should be able to optimise away any performance differences between the two examples. So use Future.immediate(), it's shorter.

Note: as [Justin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328353/in-dart-is-creating-a-future-completing-it-and-returning-it-less-efficient-tha/13352694#13352694), Future.immediate() used to be synchronous, and this is no longer the case.